# How to access global variable from class method

Tags: powershell

Sorry for bothing, just a quick question. How can I access to global variable like `$pid` from class method? The following code results compile error.

```
class C {
  C() {
    Write-Host $pid
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define it as a global variable, otherwise it will look in the methods scope.

```
Write-Host $Global:pid
```